# Openshift Zones and PV Claims

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift, openshift-origin

I've got a basic OpenShift Origin cluster set up in AWS. I've got 3 controllers, and 3 workers. Both are split across three AZs, so I have one controller and a worker in us-east-1a, one in 1b, and one of each in 1c.

Everything seems happy, but I can not figure out a way to create a PV claim in a specific AZ. It doesn't matter for a pod that has one volume, but when I need a pod with two or more, it can't get scheduled because the PVs are spread across zones.

What's the correct approach here? It seems label selectors are not supported in AWS, what's the alternative? Perhaps I need to change my openshift_node_labels -- right now all 6 are set to `{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}` which seems right based on the docs, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you reference PVCs in your deployment / pod spec directly, so that you can then manualy create them and get a working PV attached.

If that is the case, I would strongly encurage you to switch from that manual/static approach to a more dunamic / declarative way of managing storage via volumeClaimTemplates in your deployment. It will manage a set of PVCs for your pods in a completely dynamic way, giving you also ability to scale without manual labor.

Example of volumeClaimTemplates use : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#components

This should solve your issues and streamline the way you work with persistent storage at the same time.